# TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ys' (Python)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm doing some basic plotting with matplotlib 3.6.2 of an Artificial Neural Network for an online class for Tensorflow 2.0 that uses Colab and I'm doing it in VS Code with Tensorflow 2.3.0, it works in Jupyter Notebooks, but I'm getting this error running it in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "annr.py", line 43, in <module>
    plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='loss')
  File "C:\Users\calem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2842, in plot
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ys'
```

Here is the entire script up to this point:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('tf version:' + tf.__version__)

# %% [markdown]
# 

# %%
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# %%
# Make the dataset
N = 1000
X = np.random.random((N, 2)) * 6 - 3 # uniformly distributed (-3, +3)
Y = np.cos(2*X[:,0]) + np.cos(3*X[:,1])

# %%
# y = cos(2x_1) + cos(3x_2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], Y)
# plt.show()

# %%


# %%
# Build the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

# %%
# Compile and fit & plot the loss
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
r = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100)
# Plot the loss
plt.plot(r.history['loss'], label='loss')
```

Comment: Matplotlib expects a list of X coordinates and a list of Y coordinates separately, one after another.

Comment: Is `r.history['loss']` a tuple packing the xs and ys? in that case does unpacking the tuple with `plt.plot(*r.history['loss'], label = 'loss']` help?

Answer (score 2):

> it works in Jupyter Notebooks, but I'm getting this error running it in the console:

In current versions of Matplotlib, the x-coordinates can be omitted for plotting, giving only Y values to plot, and it will infer that the X values should be a sequence 0, 1, ... up to however many values are needed.

Some older versions apparently do not support this (I was unable to pinpoint when this was implemented). Specify x-coordinates for the plotted points explicitly, or upgrade Matplotlib.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the help. I'm baffled why it would work in Jupyter Notebooks but not in the console. This was the code snippet fix: "loss = r.history['loss'];
plt.plot(list(range(np.shape(loss)[0])), loss, label='loss')"

Comment: Because the notebook is using a different installation of Python, which has a different version of Matplotlib installed.

Comment: Thank you so much. All I had to type was "pip install matplotlib --upgrade" to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was running multiple version of the Python kernel. The officially recommended way to use Tensorflow in Windows is using WSL2 (Windows System Linux) using the official [Tf install instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). WSL2 is a real version of Ubuntu inside of Windows, and Tf is not officially recommended ot be used with Conda for Windows anymore due to issues with the nVidia GPU drivers.